# How to allow user to set destination folder for downloaded files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, browser

In my web application there is a download button, when user clicks on it a file gets downloaded to the "Downloads" folder. I want to add an option where user can select the folder in which the file should be downloaded.

[image]

How can I do this? Is there any plugin available for this?

Comment: File download destination is controlled by the browser. As a user, I don't want your site to be able to put any files in my Application Data/cookies/Windows folders.

Comment: in simple you cant.!!. for the security purpose you can't change the locaton of the download folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to choose the user's download location with javascript or jquery. This can only be set from the user's end, It contains on the browser. [otherwise it would violate user's security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453798/specify-default-download-folder-possibly-with-javascript). What you can suggest is the file's name. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235709/set-file-download-destination-using-extjs)

Comment: Yes but how can we trigger the "save as" menu in Javascript ? That way the user will be able to select the folder to save.

Comment: For you and others who are searching for an answer, maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525256/prompt-a-download-location-instead-of-downloading-directly

Comment: To trigger a "Save As" dialog you'll have to use the **File System Access API** which is not supported by all browsers. Read here for further information https://stackoverflow.com/a/70001920/9064287