# HTML5 Download Attribute to Selected Folder

Tags: html

I cannot seem to figure this out. I wrote a HTML5 script and I keep getting auto download to default folder.

HTML5 code :

```
<a href="../admin/gambar/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" class="btn btn-success" role="button" download>
```

So, what code to select a destination folder first and then download the file ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The destination of the 'download' is controlled by browser and you may not modify or even get the information via pure JavaScript code (exposing user's file system info is a security risk to browser), read more on [Download A File At Different Location Using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5)

Imagine that one stores his downloads at `C:\CompanyName\RealName\PhoneNumber\Adress\`

### Edit 1-

This is a browser behavior that auto-download file to the default folder, like Google Chrome you could see this help article https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=14681

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help. I will try first :D