# PHP - How to let users save a file to a specific folder on their computer?

Tags: php, download

So I am thinking maybe through a form, similar to how you would do image upload, but instead of freely choosing a file from your computer to a chosen folder on the server, then saving a specific file from server to a freely chosen folder on the computer.

```
<form action="save.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Save File" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        //save file to chosen folder on computer.
    }
?>
```

Kinda just like when you save a document on your computer and get to save it in any folder you choose.

Comment: That's called "download" and is supported by Apache by default.

Comment: `<input type="file"....` is for picking up a file from the client machine and transmitting it to the server

Comment: @RiggsFolly haha yes indeed. I believe you have misunderstood my question. I don't want the user to save the file to the server, I want them to save a file from the server to a folder of their choice on their own computer.

Comment: Browser handles that, when ever a user download, the browser will let them choose where thy wanna save, if its not specified by default @DanielAlsaker

Comment: See the Dup Question and answer for how thats done

Comment: @RiggsFolly This does not solve my problem, as it just directly downloads it to the downloads folder on the users computer. I want the user to be able to choose, from the website, which folder the file should be saved to.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Is there no way to make the browser do this? Like if you make a "save as" button. I know the user could just right click and choose the save as option, but just for an example, are there no ways of making that kinda function?

Comment: @DanielAlsaker Read here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5

Comment: It only directly downloads it to the `downloads` folder if the user has set their browser to automatically put all downloads into that folder. You cannot control what the user of your system does with those settings.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile ah, I see. Too bad... Thank you for providing an answer!