# How do I allow files to be downloaded to a folder other than the Downloads folder?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am able to use the HTML5 Download attribute to specify a file for download to the user's declared downloads folder, but what I would like to do is allow for users to create a "portal" that specifies a directory that future files can be downloaded to.

The wording is confusing so I'll use an example:

User will be using the site to exchange source code with a coworker. However, whenever the using downloads his coworker's source code, it always defaults to his Browser designated "downloads" folder. Is it possible to have the User be able to specify *on the website* that he wants it downloaded to a specific directory? Namely, his workspace for whatever project he is collaborating on.

Hopefully, this is descriptive enough. I really can't find any tools for this online.

Comment: Sorry, that's purely up the the browser; otherwise Joe Malevolent could set things up to override your system/password files, etc

Comment: ^^Mark beat me to it, it's up to user where they save.. imagine how many vulnerabilities it would open up if you could choose where to save

Comment: Would it be possible to use the site in conjunction with a client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible as the download location is controller by the browser.

If you want to know more give the page a read [Download A File At Different Location Using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5)