# How to save json file to specific folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, html, angular5

how to save the json file to specific folder or depending on user choosing folder?Here i am using angular 5

Comment: Show us what you already have.

Comment: This is a browser related confoguration, you can't manage it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download A File At Different Location Using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5)

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**. You can't change the way browsers behave. Browsers are set the way users like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. Only the user can decide where he/she wants to save the file. I guess the reason your files gets downloaded to the downloads folder is that you've saved that option in your browser. 
Check out filesaver.js. You won't be able achieve what you want but it enables some cool nifty features.