# PDF file to be downloaded in a particular folder using JSPDF

Tags: jquery, download

I have used JSPDF and download a PDF file which is saved in DOWNLOAD folder in my computer, but I need that particular downloaded PDF file to be saved in a particular folder which I have specified.

I have pasted my code below.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4'); 
pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 2.00;
var elementHandler = { 
   '#Export': function (element, renderer) { 
                return true; }
};
var options = { 'elementHandlers': elementHandler, background:'#FFFFFF',pagesplit: true,};
pdf.addHTML($("#pdf")[0], 5, 10, options, function() { pdf.save('test.pdf');});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download A File At Different Location Using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.