# Downloading files to specific directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-core, download

I'd like to know if it was possible to perform direct downloads to a specified folder in a .Net Core MVC application. Currently, I'm returning a File from my controller and am prompted with the browser's generic download window. I'd like to know if it was possible to skip this window entirely and download it directly to the path string specified by me on the code or at least to show up on that same path when choosing the place to save.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related with ASP.Net Core. It is a browser side challenge and it posses security risk. Hence it is not possible to do that on nearly any browser which follows known security standards.

please see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34871076/1118978