# How to direct a csv exported from an html button save to a specific folder location

Tags: html, datatables, download, save

Goal: Create a button on my html page that downloads a csv and saves it to a specific folder location. (I know this can be done in browser settings, but I am looking to be able to hard code this somehow into my web page.)

Currently, I am using the datatables plug-in to display and filter data on my html page queried from my MySQL database.

Ultimately I want to be able to skip the "Save As" window that pops up after pressing the download button and have the csv file go directly to the specified folder.

Comment: Luckily this is not possible. It would be a huge security threat if it was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download A File At Different Location Using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5)

Comment: So even if I am working on an isolated machine not connected to anything and am not worried about the security threat, there would not be a way to bypass this?

Comment: There isn't. The browser cannot tell that you are in a compketely isolated environment. Even tge possibility to override this behaviour would be a huge security risk. Simply forget this idea.