# How to store file to specific folder using pdfMake?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdfmake

I have used a third party library which is pdfMake. Generally, pdfMake is used to convert the HTMl to pdf. I want to download that file to  specific folder. This file.pdf is downloading to the default folder i.e. download.

This is the code which is downloading the file to download folder, I want to download that file to a different folder.

```
$scope.exportpdf = function () {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportpdf'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500,
                    }]
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('file.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Check this 2 answers where described completely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5

Comment: That means I can't change download location after converting HTML to PDF?