# Hi all Can we set a different location path to downloaded "screenshot in use react screenshot"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

how to save screen shot in different location other than mypc/downloads

I am tried and its default saving into mypc/downloads

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download A File At Different Location Using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5)

Comment: Do follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Add few more details of what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far in detail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.