# How to prompt user for download with HTML5

Tags: html, google-chrome, download, anchor

I'm using chrome and I have a link like this

```
<a href="http://textfiles.com/100/ad.txt" download="foo.txt">try me</a>
```

according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) ...

> [download] is used as the pre-filled file name in the Save prompt *(the user can
>   still change the file name if they want)*.

However, when I click the link with Chrome it **does not** allow me to change the name.

Is this a bug in chrome?

Is there a way to work around, so that it will allow user to change the name?

Answer (score 1):

After more research I think it is not possible.  The browsers all do whatever they want, and the MDN has little to say about it.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27525335/1812732