# Change default location download of browser by javascript ?

Tags: javascript

as the title, have anyway to change default location download of browser ( i'm working with IE9) by javascript ?

Comment: Short answer: no way to do it in JS.

Comment: I certainly hope not...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow user to set destination folder for downloaded files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333443/how-to-allow-user-to-set-destination-folder-for-downloaded-files)

Comment: Unless "that technology who's name cannot be spoken out loudly" (activeX) is used (or a browser helper object) the answer is no!

Comment: or can i do that with AngularJS, can customize directive ?..

Comment: NO!, security reasons prohibit this. You don't want some kind of scriptkiddy pumping files into locations you don't want them to be. Cannot be done with all tools based upon JavaScript.

Comment: What Klaus Prinoth said. Possible [dublicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333443/how-to-allow-user-to-set-destination-folder-for-downloaded-files)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Javascript has no control on the user's local file system.