# how to save a excel file in a particular path?

Tags: asp.net

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=abc.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
```

I am using the code above to download an Excel file but I want to download the Excel file to a specific path.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not possible as you don't have right about the directory structure of client machine.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. Server can't to locate client machine for particular destanation of downloading.

[RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183#section-2.3):

> The receiving MUA SHOULD NOT respect any directory path information
> that may seem to be present in the filename parameter.  The filename
> should be treated as a terminal component only.  Portable
> specification of directory paths might possibly be done in the future
> via a separate Content-Disposition parameter, but no provision is made
> for it in this draft.

Comment: It is possible only on client-side due security reasons. For more information you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235709/set-file-download-destination-using-extjs

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done by server side it's your os and browser settins which tells where the downloaded file should be placed as Alexgender says

> "The filename should be treated as terminal component only"