# choose download directory(browse for folder dialog) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

In my web application if user selects files and clicks on a download button, a REST web service call will be made to fetch the files. My requirement is to download the fetched files in user's local drive by popping up a dialogue box. The dialog box should let the user to choose location to save the files chosen.

I already browsed and couldn't get what i need. I've attached my required folder image.
[image]
It would be really helpful if someone helps me on this. Thanks.

**Note:**
Also This links says it's not possible and not correct as well. Kindly let me know if it's true. [Set file download destination using ExtJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235709/set-file-download-destination-using-extjs)

Answer (score 1):

You can't set file download destination in any way with javascript unless its the filesystem API

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to add a Content-Disposition header to the HTTP response made to the download request. This header should be like:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>`

Comment: Sure. I'll try this. Thanks.