# Specify download location in Django

Tags: python, django-1.9

Is there a way to specify a download location in Django?

My page allows the user to

- Click a button run to a EXE in the background
- Then gives the user a new page where the download option is available
- User clicks the download, and it downloads the latest file it generated

I read in a HTML [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612566/how-to-specify-download-location-in-html-using-javascript) that you cannot force the browser to download a specific location. I am wondering if Django has an option that lets you do this.

```
def DownloadZip(request, zipname, prodVersID):
    print(zipname)
    zip_path = "C:/fbw/firmware/main/sys/" + zipname
    zip_file =  open(zip_path, 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' %zipname
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(zip_path)
    zip_file.close()

    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I concluded that the reference [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612619/5104387) also reflects on Django. Django does not offer such feature, it is a security feature of the web browser that does not allow you to specify download location.

Credit to [Darren](http://Darren%20Willows)

> Whether the browser asks the user or not is down to the preferences in
>   the browser.
>
> You can't bypass those preference, otherwise it would violate user's
>   security.