# Server image download in a client machine folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

Server image should be download in a local client machine in a particular path 
using javascript or jquery.

Is there any way to download the image in a particular path where we cannot use server side script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612566/how-to-specify-download-location-in-html-using-javascript) question.

Answer (score 1):

With only js and jquery it is not possible.  Maybe with a browser extension it can be possible. But with js and jquery you dont have ability to write local machine.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply.