# AngularJs Download a file from server and store it to given path on local machine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to download a file from server and store it on a specific path on local machine.

```
<a href="<downloadLink>" download="fileName">Download</a>
```

Using this anchor tag downloads the file but in default location. I want to store it to specific location.

Comment: Specifying download location is not allowed because it poses a security risk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify download location in Html using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612566/how-to-specify-download-location-in-html-using-javascript)

Comment: check this link https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload