# Saving a element data from HTML into a specific folder in HDD using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, save, element, getelementbyid

In my Java Script , I am getting the below element from HTML. After getting it I want to save it in some folder on my local drive.
Can any one help me with this.I am using zip.js to unzip files. After unzipping , all the zip file content coming in fileList and it is shown in the browser . When i click any one of the file it will get downloaded but instead showing it on browser I want to download all files in local drive after unzipping. Please see --gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo2.html

```
var fileList = document.getElementById("file-list");
```

Comment: It is not clear just by `data` that what you are going to save .

Comment: I am using zip.js to unzip files. After unzipping , all the zip file content  coming in fileList and it is shown in the browser . When i click any one of the file it will get downloaded but instead showing it on browser I want to download all files in local drive after unzipping. Please see --https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo2.html

Comment: Please have a look into the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript
You might need to restructure your HTML code and it will enable possibility for the user to download attached files

Answer (score 0):

If your code is same as the demo, then you can loop through the `li` elements inside fileList and call `click` function on each of the links.

```
const fileList = $("#file-list"); //get file-list element by id
const li = fileList.children;     //get li elements inside fileList
for (let item of li) {            //loop through all li elements
    item.children.item(0).click() //get 1st child element (link) and click it to download
}
```

Note I used jQuery as the demo site allowed it, but if it is not possible for you then you can also use plain JavaScript.

Comment: Using it can i saved it in some target folder provided by user?

Comment: Download folders are specified by browser settings, you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612566/how-to-specify-download-location-in-html-using-javascript) change it through JavaScript

Comment: So how can i Unzipp a zip file and saved in a folder automatically using zip.js

Comment: As i said it is up to the user to select their download folder in browser settings, if you need to use browser and JavaScript for unzipping you have to use that selected folder.