# how to download automatically without print pop up (node js)

Tags: html, css, node.js, pdf

I'm making a project where when the page opens, the pdf file is automatically downloaded, I managed to use this:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        window.print();


    })
```

but I want when windows opens the file is directly downloaded to the directory that I have defined, for example D: / myproject.

is there any way? I don't use pdf library because I make pdf with css myself.

thank you

Comment: How can you know if the user has the directory you defined? Maybe they have not `D://` at all? Anyway, you can't control where the file will be saved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612619/863110

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify download location in Html using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612566/how-to-specify-download-location-in-html-using-javascript)

Comment: so my problem, I want to disable pop up print and make it directly downloaded in the directory

Comment: @rash you can't. Browser decides if a file should be downloaded directly to a user-specified directory or it should ask. It would be a security vulnerability otherwise. Imagine any website uploading files to your machine without asking.

Comment: As much as I understand, you're using the browser print option to convert your page to PDF. If you want to skip the print step, you'll have to generate the PDF by yourself.  You can use a tool like jsPDF to achieve this. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24825130/863110)

Comment: so can window.print () download directly on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` will not be accessible on server side code.

If you want to download file in browser, on just open the web page the you can use [res.download()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) as follows:

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  const file = `${__dirname}/upload-folder/file_name.pdf`;
  res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
});
```

As you want to download the file in a specific directory, so you can use the [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-file)

```
var download = require('download-file')

app.get('/download', function(req, res){
   var url = ${__dirname} + "/upload-folder/file_name.pdf";
   var options = {
    directory: "path of directory/",
    filename: "file_name.pdf"
   }

   download(url, options, function(err){
     if (err) throw err

     res.send("Done"); // Set disposition and send it.
   }) 

});
```

Edit: To convert the html code into the pdf you can use the npm module  [jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)

Comment: It seems like OP wants to do it on the client side (aka browser)

Comment: `because I make pdf with css myself`. Also, the question is about set the destination - `I managed to use this... the file is directly downloaded to the directory that I have defined`

Comment: so my problem, I want to disable pop up print and make it directly downloaded in the directory

Comment: Is download-file module asking for download Pop up?

Comment: I want to download but my pdf file is still html, how do I make it pdf?

Comment: oh, dear. ... HTML to pdf is a different question... I have replied just for download the file in a specific and in the browser as per required. to get that as pdf you can use jspdf like tool

Comment: The download function here overwrites the OS default download folder?