# On click of download button, window dialog box should appear to choose its download location

Tags: javascript, html, angular

On click of a download button, I need a window that should open. User should be able to select any location for the download from the system window that pops up

This are the Request parameters I am passing to the api-

```
"method": "downloadCSV"

"project": "IB_SimpleProject_V2"

"dataSourceId": "DSR.4"
```

This is Response I am getting from it -

```
{ "downloadUrl": "http://localhost:8080/InBetween/...../.csv", "fileName": "<File name of csv with extension>" "message":"Download Successful", "code": 100 }
```

HTML:`<a [href]="url" target="_blank" [download]="filename" (click)="downloadFile()">Download</a>`

TS:

```
 downloadFile(){
    this.getDownload(project, dataSourceId).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.code === 100) {
        this.url = res.downloadUrl;
        this.filename = res.fileName;
      }
    });
  }
```

But I am not getting how to choose its location of download by choosing the path from the window dialog box
I am using Javascript and Angular 2+
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with letting the browser handle the system side of things like choosing a save location? Besides, the app does not have direct access to the OS running the browser.

Comment: Actually, we have a customer requirement of that in which user should be allowed to choose its download location

Comment: It's a browser setting. Eg. in Firefox it's under _Options -> General -> Downloads -> Always ask you where to save files_. Now the browser will open the Save window for each download.

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to specifiy the download location due to security.

Helpful threads for your reference:

[Specify default download folder - possibly with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453798/specify-default-download-folder-possibly-with-javascript)

[User specified download location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677281/user-specified-download-location)