# Download a file to specific location on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know JavaScript has no access to filesystem, but just want to check if there is any other alternative. I am using the below line to download the file on click.

```js
var mySpreadsheet = jspreadsheet(document.getElementById('spreadsheet1'), {
    csv: 'https://abc.xyz.com/IT/doc/test/library/Web/jspreadsheet.csv',
    csvHeaders: true,
    tableOverflow: true,
    columns: [
        { type: 'text', width: 30 },
        { type: 'text', width: 700 },
        { type: 'text', width: 60 },
        { type: 'text', width: 120 },
        { type: 'dropdown', width: 120, source: ['Pending', 'Completed'] },
        { type: 'button', width: 50, source: ['Email'] },
    ]
});
document.getElementById('save_excel').onclick = function (e) {
    mySpreadsheet.download();
//I wanted to download file to - https://abc.xyz.com/IT/doc/test/library. 
}
```

```html
<body>
<button id='save_excel'>Save</button>`enter code here`
</body>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: No you can't for security reason

Comment: What is `e`? This should cause an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User specified download location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677281/user-specified-download-location)